# Regex - Match all charactes between curly braces as long as certain string is present

Tags: javascript, regex

I have paragraphs like this:

```
"{~1.6} This is another paragraph {~1} with curly braces.{~6.8}"
```

I want to match `{~<int or float>}`

So far I've came to this regex: `/\{(\~(\d*\.?\d+),?)\}/g`

It works just fine but sometimes there will be some other characters before or after `~<int or float>` like this:

```
"{:.class ~1.6 #id} This is another paragraph {~1 .class #id} with curly braces.{:#id ~6.8}"
```

I don't know in advance the content before or after `~<int or float>`, all that I know is that all the content is between curly braces.

How can I match every `{<some content here>}` as long as it contains at least one `~<int or float>` occurrence?

Comment: Could curly braces be nested?

Comment: @markalex no, there is not curly brace nested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/{([^}]*(~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}/
```

Match the brace, any number of non-brace characters, then the bit you were interested in (tilde and a number, with optional decimal point and decimal digits), then possibly some more non-brace characters, and finally the closing brace. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rI55XA/1)

Note that a brace does not need to be escaped in JavaScript unless it contains a valid quantifier (number or pair of numbers separated by a comma, possibly with one number missing), though it doesn't hurt; tilde does not need escaping at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
/{(?=.~(\d.?\d+))([^{}]+)}/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surround your `~number` with classes excluding pairing braces, like this:

```
\{[^}]*(\~(\d*\.?\d+),?)[^{]*\}
```

Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/ApqFv7/1).

Answer (score 0):

To remove all characters that are outside of the curly braces, you can use the following regular expression:

`\{[^{}]*\}`

This pattern will take your example strings and output the following:

- `"{~1.6}{~1}{~6.8}"`
- `"{:.class ~1.6 #id}{~1 .class #id}{:#id ~6.8}"`

The pattern above is simpler but you can use this expression if you also need to ignore empty braces, ie `{}`

`\{[^{}]*\}(?=[^{}]*\{[^{}]*\})`

Comment: Welcome to SO! This doesn't answers the question. There should be the content of the curly braces as result, not the text between. `{result}` NOT `{...}result{...}`.

Comment: my mistake, I didn't understand the desired result. This will work: `(?<=\{)[^\{\}]*\}(?=\})|[^{\}]+` it will result in this string `"{:.class ~1.6 #id}{~1 .class #id}{:#id ~6.8}"`, although I'm sure the other answers will work too.

Comment: So edit your answer and correct the regex there.