# Regex - match a pattern only if it is after or before certain pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have giant string (markdown) that contains something like this:

> ## Header 1
>
> {~1.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam
> turpis, {~2.0} vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~3.0}
>
> {~4.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~5.0}
> vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~6.0}
>
> {~7.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~8.0}
> vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~9.0}
>
> ## Header 2
>
> {~10.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~11.0}
> vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~12.0}
>
> {~113.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~14.0}
> vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~15.0}
>
> {~16.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~17.0}
> vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~18.0}
>
> ## Header 3
>
> {~19.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~20.0}
> vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~21.0}
>
> {~22.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~23.0}
> vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~24.0}
>
> {~25.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~26.0}
> vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~27.0}

This is a marker `{~x.x}`

And I will call "section" to the combination of a header and one more more paragraphs.

I need to match the first and the last marker of every section.

Currently I'm using this regex `/\s?{([^}]*(~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}\s?/g` in javascript that I got from the selected answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75871756/regex-match-all-charactes-between-curly-braces-as-long-as-certain-string-is-pr) to capture all the markers, but now I need to modify it to capture only the first and the last ones from every 'section'.

The string comes from user input so I cannot know in advance how many paragraphs a 'section' will have neither the content of the headers, all that I know is that there will be at least one section (meaning one header followed by x amount of paragraphs).

Comment: Is the giant string markdown? Looks like it... 

Fronend or backend?

Comment: How is 3.0 before or after a heading?  It is surrounded with text just like 2.0.  Or do you mean in the sentence before the heading?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah right, I should be more specific, I need to capture the marker only if it is after or before a `##<followed by any character including spaces>` pattern

Comment: But {~3.0} is in the middle of text? I mean every {~x.x} is 'after or before a ##<followed by any character including spaces>' ?

Comment: @ThomasFrank yeah it's markdown, don't get the question though, does it matter if I'm working on backend or frontend? I'm just getting that markdown as a string and need to capture certain parts of it.

Comment: Because if is markdown converting it to html might make it easier... and including a library to do so can be a little bit different on backend vs. frontend.  If 3.0 is a mistake in your array - then if this was converted to html you would only have to search for numbers that are first and last in a paragraph tag...

Comment: This will work (but has limitations...)  `(?|{([^}]*(~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}(?=[^.]*.\n\n##)|(?<=## Header [0-9]\n\n){([^}]*(~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}|(?<=## Header [0-9][0-9]\n\n){([^}]*(~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)})`  If that's works for you I can write an answer.  https://regex101.com/r/M3Lhym/1  It doesn't pick up 9.0 because it is nowhere near a `##`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: :) Starts to look like when I wrote a lot of Perl back in the days. Well done... but as with all complex regex:s a bit hard to maintain :)

Comment: @ThomasFrank yes, every `{~x.x}` marker is in the middle of the text always

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I'm pretty sure that this question has the [tag:javascript] tag and ECMAScript flavor doesn't support the branch reset group syntax.

Comment: @InSync  Sorry - I had the wrong thing selected in Regex101...  This takes that out but the submatches are in different groups  `{([^}]*(?:~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}(?=[^.]*.\n\n##)|(?<=## Header [0-9]\n\n){([^}]*(?:~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}|(?<=## Header [0-9][0-9]\n\n){([^}]*(?:~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}`  https://regex101.com/r/M3Lhym/2

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, it works with the current example 'headers' texts `## Header <1-9>`, but in my app I don't know what text will be after `##`, I should have specified that on the OP, I will update it. And I just realized that 9.0 marker is not after or before any 'header', but I need that one too, I will include that part too in my update.

Comment: I feel really stupid - but looking at the example I still don't understand why 3.0 is in the array, but not 2.0, or 9.0 but not 8.0

Comment: @GhostOrder  That's what I meant by `(but has limitations...)`   You can't make a non fixed width look behind....

Comment: @ThomasFrank  I assumed he wanted marker in the sentence after or before the `##`  So that's why my regex looks for the marker and then some stuff followed by a `.`  Of course he also wants the {9.0} which isn't anywhere near a `##`  So I think that means he wants the markes in the first and last sentence of each heading.  And I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @ThomasFrank no is my bad, I'm updating the question

Comment: Ok, forget about the `##`  What if we just say the markers in the first and last sentence of every paragraph: `(?<=\n){([^}]*(?:~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}|{([^}]*(?:~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}(?=[^.]*.\n|[^.]*.$)` https://regex101.com/r/M3Lhym/3  Or can a `##` delimited section have more than one paragraph?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah "*You can't make a non fixed width look behind*": No, unlike PCRE, ES supports that.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the first and last in each paragraph, basically... (Unless there a level 3 headlines in the real string... of course. So no @JerryJeremiah I don't think you can make that assumption...

I would go with parsing it to HTML, putting it in a "fake DOM", like Cheerio and getting it from there, although I understand that a reg ex would be elegant...

Comment: OR: How about just splitting on \n## first and then loop each string and check for the first and last number in it?

Comment: Ok, what about this one.  I think it does everything you want: `(?<=##[^\n]+\n\n){([^}]*(?:~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}|{([^}]*(?:~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}(?=[^.]*\.\n\n##[^\n]+\n|[^.]*\.$)` https://regex101.com/r/M3Lhym/4

Comment: Allright I just updated the question, hopefully it's better explained now

Comment: This is my final one - I think it does what you want: `(?<=##[^\n]+\n\n){([^}]*(?:~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}|{([^}]*(?:~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}(?=[^.]*\.\n\n##[^\n]+\n|[^.]*\.\n*$)` https://regex101.com/r/M3Lhym/6

Comment: You've changed the input but are no longer giving an expected output. Please [edit] your question with that, otherwise how can we reverify our answers?

Comment: Another idea:  [`str.split(/^\s*##[^#].*/m).forEach(v => { if(m = v.trim().match(/^{~[\d.]+}|{~[\d.]+}$/g)) console.log(m); });`](https://tio.run/##pdM9b4MwEAbgnV9xEh0gbU0M@aBC6VapQ7eOSVAs41BXGCPbsFDy16lbKZShAyKeLPlePeeT/UkaoqnilXls4r4vmAFtFOzg5LrwykjGFGDHAbvaC0bLDt6kYgJ4pWsBmSykAs0NEMEMgneWAZVlXjPIOBFgalVx/WCj4U@04YawawFTxMYorYUmJZSMIlsW2bKrtpqvradpm5G2na/F07SnQfsbbTiMdjnfx3haAzgc3Rfj6AZxNVFcj8XNDeB2Ihj/M@TolDiOfdVIVwU3XpAe9MJ196l7RItA@Ogs1QuhH14Du2dobZifPWG/QIOM4sLzkSDGHgdpe9kfMnS8776G3V2Q@/6vZ9vSsmCokLkn/MTp/KTvvwE) (JS demo at tio.run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my variant, less regexp:y than most others perhaps, but it works:

```
function getNumbers(str) {
  return `\n${str}`.split('\n## ')
    .map(x => [...x.matchAll(/\{~(\d|\.)*\}/g)].map(x => x[0]))
    .map(x => [x[0], x.slice(-1)]).flat(2).filter(x => x)
    .map(x => +x.replace(/[\{\}~]/g, ''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with lookarounds, which JS supports.

Since we're reusing the original pattern a lot, let's store it in a variable:

```js
const pattern = String.raw`{([^}]*(?:~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}`;
```

A string that doesn't contain the pattern above looks like this, where `[^]` denotes "all character", similar to a `.` with the `s` flag:

```js
`(?:(?!${pattern})[^])*`
```

From that, we construct our lookahead and lookbehind:

```js
// Pattern, anything that doesn't contain pattern, then header or end of string (not end of line).
const lookahead = `${pattern}(?=(?:(?!${pattern})[^])*(?:^##.+|(?![^])))`;

// Header, anything that doesn't contain pattern, then pattern itself.
const lookbehind = `(?<=^##.+$(?:(?!${pattern})[^])*)${pattern}`;
```

Here's how our final steps go:

```js
const regex = new RegExp(`${lookbehind}|${lookahead}`, 'gm');

// Filter out unmatched groups.
[...text.matchAll(regex)].map(match => match.filter(Boolean));
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function match(string) {
  const pattern = String.raw`{([^}]*(?:~\d*(?:\.\d+)?)[^}]*)}`;
  const lookahead = `${pattern}(?=(?:(?!${pattern})[^])*(?:^##.+|(?![^])))`;
  const lookbehind = `(?<=^##.+$(?:(?!${pattern})[^])*)${pattern}`;
  const regex = new RegExp(`${lookbehind}|${lookahead}`, 'gm');
  
  console.log(regex); // Just to show you how monstrous it is.
  
  return string.matchAll(regex);
}

const text = `
## Header 1

{~1.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~2.0} vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~3.0}

{~4.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~5.0} vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~6.0}

{~7.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~8.0} vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~9.0}

## Header 2

{~10.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~11.0} vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~12.0}

{~113.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~14.0} vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~15.0}

{~16.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~17.0} vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~18.0}

## Header 3

{~19.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~20.0} vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~21.0}

{~22.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~23.0} vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~24.0}

{~25.0} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed congue diam turpis, {~26.0} vitae congue erat accumsan nec. {~27.0}
`.trim();

console.log([...match(text)].map(match => match.filter(Boolean)));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```